# How to wait for inner function to complete before returning the outer function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am creating a function which returns data from the `EC2.describeInstanceStatus` method of the NodeJS AWS SDK. Here's what it looks like:

```
function getInstanceDetails(): sdk.EC2.DescribeInstancesResult[] {
  let instanceDetails: sdk.EC2.DescribeInstancesResult[] = [];
  let ec2Query = new sdk.EC2();

  ec2Query.describeInstanceStatus(
      function (err, data): void {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
          else {
              instanceDetails.forEach(instance => {
                  instanceDetails.push(instance);
              });
              console.log(data);
          }
       });

  return instanceDetails;
}
```

I have found my function returns an empty array, which seems to be because the callback above it does not finish executing before the return statement is executed.

Although I know this, I am not really sure how to ensure callback function has *finished* before returning the result.

Any ideas for how I can make that happen?

Read more about the `describeInstanceStatus` method here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeInstanceStatus-property

Comment: Maybe, you can use inner return callback, so whenever it's called then the outer function can be completed.

Answer (score 0):

Because this operation is asynchronous, you have to use Promises or `async/await` functions. Here is how to rewrite it using either option:

Promises:

```
function getInstanceDetails(): Promise<sdk.EC2.DescribeInstancesResult[]> {
  let instanceDetails: sdk.EC2.DescribeInstancesResult[] = [];
  let ec2Query = new sdk.EC2();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ec2Query.describeInstanceStatus((err, data) => {
      // This will reject the promise in case of error
      // If this happens, callback provided to `.catch` will be fired
      if(err) return reject(err)

      // This happens on success, callback in `.then` will be called
      resolve(data)
    })
  }).then((data) => {
    // Did you mean to do `data.forEach` here? This code
    // seems a bit weird, but I'm not sure, what you want
    instanceDetails.forEach(instance => {
      instanceDetails.push(instance);
    });
    console.log(data);
    
    // This value then can be used by consumers of `getInstanceDetails` function
    return instanceDetails
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err, err.stack)
  })
}
```

async/await:

```
async function getInstanceDetails(): Promise<sdk.EC2.DescribeInstancesResult[]> {
  let instanceDetails: sdk.EC2.DescribeInstancesResult[] = [];
  let ec2Query = new sdk.EC2();

  try {
    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ec2Query.describeInstanceStatus((err, data) => {
      // Analog of throwing an error, `catch` block will be fired
      if(err) return reject(err)
      // Becomes return value of `await new Promise`
      resolve(data)
    })
    instanceDetails.forEach(instance => {
      instanceDetails.push(instance);
    });
    console.log(data);
    
    // This value will can be used by consumers of `getInstanceDetails` function
    return instanceDetails
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e, e.stack)
  }
}
```

There only other way to deal with asynchronous actions are callback functions, but you can read on the internet, why they are not great, compared to Promises.

The drawback is that now all functions that use `getInstanceDetails` will have to use promises or `async/await` syntax as well:

```
getInstanceDetails().then(instanceDetails => {
  // Do something with instanceDetails
})
```

or

```
async function doSomething() {
  const instanceDetails = await getInstanceDetails()
  // Do something with instanceDetails
}
doSomething()
```